# CSS - border consisting of triangles

Tags: javascript, html, css

There are many questions here about one triangle as bottom border, but I want to have many triangles at the bottom like in the picture below. How can it be done?

[image]

Comment: Well that may be an image, not CSS.

Comment: You can use a small triangle as a background-image and repeat it throughout your container.

Comment: @TorjescuSergiu I checked the source of this site, there is no image there

Comment: @jakub1998 what is the site URL? I'm curious, the only way i knew is using small image as a background.

Comment: tell us the website link

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, there is an image of a few triangles, it was so nested that I didn't notice.

Comment: @IvanVilanculo we can do it without image, linear-gradient will do it. check the duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into ths CSS property. It allows to use images as borders

```
border-image: url('link-to-your-image.png') <spacing>;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image

Answer (score -1):

I think it's an image. You can take this image and create ::before and ::after for the section you want to make a border, and set the upper triangles as a background of ::before and the lower triangles as a background of ::after and set position absolute for both before and after. Put ::before at the top to be the top border and ::after at the bottom to be the bottom border.